# Usage Of AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap()

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am attempting to load a dll into a seperate app domain using this code:

```
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("HardwareAbstractionLayer");            
string pathToDll = @"DeviceManagement.dll";
Type t = typeof(DeviceManager);
DeviceManager myObject = (DeviceManager)domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(pathToDll, t.FullName);
```

I get the error:
"Constructor on type 'DeviceManagement.DeviceManager' not found."

It appears that the dll uses a singleton pattern and I'm not sure how to use the AppDomain function in that case.  Here is the constructor code for the dll:

```
private DeviceManager() { }
private static readonly DeviceManager instance = new DeviceManager();
public static DeviceManager Instance { get { return instance; } }
```

Answer (score 3):

What you'll need to do is create a wrapper object to create the instance for you.

```
public sealed class DeviceManagerWrapper : MarshalByRefObject {
  public DeviceManagerWrapper(){}
  public DeviceManager DeviceManager {
    get { return DeviceManager.Instance; }
  }
}
```

Now just create an instance of `DeviceManagerWrapper` and grab the `DeviceManager` singleton through the property.

Comment: After correcting a typo you made "DeviceManeger" to "DeviceManager" I get another error saying that it could not load DeviceManagerWrapper from the assembly DeviceManager.dll.

Comment: @Robert you'll have to include the assembly information for the assembly that contains DeviceManagerWrapper

Comment: How would one go about getting assembly information from an executable?  And if I could get that information, where would I put it?

Comment: @Robert: `Assembly.LoadFrom(path)`.  However, if `DeviceManager` doesn't inherit `MarshalByRefObject`, this won't do any good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a separate entry-point class with a public constructor that has a property that returns the singleton instance.

Both classes must inherit `MarshalByRefObject`.

Comment: I'm unable to change DeviceManager so I can't make it inherit MarshalByRefObject.

Comment: @Robert: Then you should make a `MarshalByRefObject` wrapper class in the other AppDomain that forwards all method calls to the singleton instance.